# pyroot folder of a python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am following a step-by-step tutorial blog on the flask micro framework for python. 
I bumped into an issue, when they require me to 'setup' a configuration file in the root of the application folder, so it can easily be accessible if needed.
They called it `config.py`.

My question is, if the local path to my application is  `/home/test/application1/`, should I create the file inside the `./application1/` directory? What gets me confused in this somewhat obvious question is that I did a quick search for other `config.py` files in the local directory inside `/home/test/application1/`, where I found 4 other files. There were in the following directories:

```
/home/test/application1/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/testsuite/config.py
/home/test/application1/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/config.py
/home/test/application1/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/testsuite/config.py
/home/test/application1/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/config.py
```

So should I create a new `config.py` file in the directory that I first mentioned or should I add some lines in one of the previously created `config.py` files.

Here is the source of the [step-by-step tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms):

It is at the beginning, right after Configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other frameworks, Flask does not have a lot of rules, in general you can implement things in the way they make sense to you.

But note that the other `config.py` files that you found are all in the virtual environment, and are all scripts that come with Flask. They have nothing to do with the application configuration.

I wrote the tutorial you are following. In the tutorial I'm putting `config.py` outside of the application package. This is what I like, I consider the configuration separate from the application. My thinking is that you should be able to run the same application with different configuration files, so that for example, you can have a production configuration, a testing configuration and a development configuration, all different.

I hope this helps.